# ASP.NET Identity 2.0 & Web forms - Reset password if we know user's e-mail (VB)

Tags: asp.net, identity

I use ASP.NET Identity 2.0 and Web Forms.

I need to allow users to reset their passwords just by entering their e-mails if forgotten. As far as I know, I need user's ID to modify/reset a password, e-mail is not enough. So I tried the following but **it does not work**.

```
    Dim manager As UserManager = New UserManager()
    Dim user As ApplicationUser = manager.FindByEmail("user@email.com")
```

but **user is always Nothing** even if the e-mail is valid.

The following **works** fine for me:

```
    Dim manager As UserManager = New UserManager()
    Dim user As ApplicationUser = manager.Find(username, password)
```

Any suggestions why **manager.FindByEmail does not return the user**?

Thanks!

Comment: which file i need to import to access `UserManager()`

Comment: Imports Microsoft.AspNet.Identity